# mysql - delete sql row where data not match with data in array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Please can I have some help on this. I'm trying to delete SQL row in a table that are not match the data in an array.

SQL Table:

```
| id | Name  | No
------------------
| 1  | john  | 14 
| 2  | rui   | 156
| 3  | ted   | 148
| 4  | alex  | 123
| 5  | depay | 56
```

Array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => john
            [no] => 14
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => ted
            [no] => 148
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => depay
            [no] => 56
        )
)
```

Comment: `DELETE FROM yourTable WHERE \`NAME\` NOT IN ('john','ted','depay') AND \`No\` NOT IN (14,148,56)`?

Comment: What language are you using (aside from SQL)?

Comment: Sean is right assuming that you can get values from array into SQL.

Comment: at least try something before posting

Comment: Google 'php pass array to sql'.  PHP is as relevant to question as SQL.

Comment: Are the values of the column **no** unique ?

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
 [akshay@localhost tmp]$ cat test.php
 <?php

 $array = array (
   array (
     'name' => 'john',
     'no' => '14'
   ),
   array (
     'name' => 'ted',
     'no' => '148'
   ), 
   array (
     'name' => 'depay',
     'no' => '56'
   )
 );

 $table = "some_table";
 $sql   = "DELETE FROM ".$table." WHERE (NAME,NO) NOT IN (". implode(",",array_map(function($_){ return sprintf("('%s',%d)",$_['name'],$_['no']);},$array)).")";

 print $sql."\n";
 ?>
```

***Output***

```
 [akshay@localhost tmp]$ php test.php
 DELETE FROM some_table WHERE (NAME,NO) NOT IN (('john',14),('ted',148),('depay',56))
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier if you can return "id" aka primary key of the table as array. In that case you can just grab those ids and during delete operation exclude those from the equation.

```
$selectQ = 'select id from table_name'; // and no>10
$result = mysql_result($selectQ);
$ids = array();
while ($info = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $ids[] = $info['id'];
}
if($ids) {
 $deleteQ = 'delete from table_name where id not in ('.implode(",", array_values($ids)).')';
 mysql_query($deleteQ);
}
```

P.S : During select query make sure to include logic for finding those users. For example, who's "no" is greater than X.Otherwise this query in default will return all ids and eventually nothing will be deleted.